# How to implement security questions with Devise?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to implement some security questions to allow the user to reset his password.

I'm using the **devise_security_extension** and following the [instructions](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension) however I am a bit lost on how to implement the view so the user can input the answers.

I read the following post: [Implementing Security questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467729/implementing-security-questions) but it left me more confused.

**Should I create a nested form or there is some sort of generator?**

**Models**

```
class SecurityQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

class TheResource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :security_questions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The document write :

Add the captcha in the generated devise views for each controller you have activated

```
<p><%= captcha_tag %></p>
<p><%= text_field_tag :captcha %></p>
```